# Show that the set of polynomials divisible by $x-1$ cannot span $P$, the set of all polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, polynomials

Proof: (by contradiction)

Let $D$ be the set of polynomials divisible by $x-1$; $D=\{\sigma_i(x)=q_i(x)(x-1) \mid \sigma_i(x),q_i(x)\in P\}$. Considering the set of polynomials $p(x)\in P$ such that $(x-1)\nmid p(x)$. If $D$ spans $P$ then $p(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\sigma_i(x)$,for some $\sigma_i(x)\in D$ and $c_i\in\Bbb{F}$, then 
\begin{align}
p(x)&=c_1q_1(x)(x-1)+...+c_nq_n(x)(x-1)\\
&=(x-1)(c_1q_1(x)+...+c_nq_n(x))\\
\Rightarrow (x-1)\mid p(x)\\
\end{align}
Thus a contradiction.

Comment: This is fine, except that you should show (or at least mention) that there is a polynomial not divisible by $x-1$. $1$ will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct, exceept that you did not prove that there is a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $(x-1)\nmid p(x)$. Without this, your proof doesn't work.

The simplest way of doing this consists in proving that there is some polynomial outside $D$. Take $p(x)=1$, for instance. If you could write $p(x)$ as $a_1p_1(x)+\cdots+a_mp_m(x)$, with $p_1(x),\ldots,p_m(x)$ all multiples of $x-1$, then you would have $(x-1)\mid1$, which is clearly false.

Comment: I have let $p(x)$ be some arbitrary polynomial that does not have $x-1$ as one of its factors. Then tried to argue to a contradiction by assuming $p(x)$ is a expressible as a linear combination of elements in $D$. Is that not valid?

Comment: @TheLastCipher Right. I misread the first $\nmid$ sign; it looked a $\mid$ sign to me. And it is always better to provide a concrete example. Your proof would fail if there was no polynomial $p(x)$ such that $(x-1)\nmid p(x)$.

Comment: Alright. Can i simply say that $(x-2)(x-3)=x^2 - 5x +6$ is in $P$ and not divisible by $x-1$?

Comment: @TheLastCipher That is correct, of course, but why don't you just take $p(x)=1$?

Comment: Of course! haha thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Any polynomial $p(x)$ multiple of $x-1$ is such that $p(1)=0$ and this property is inherited by any linear combination. So you can't cover $q(1)\ne0$.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say :(

Comment: This is the proof. What exactly don't you understand ?

Comment: i was asking for a correction. It did looked like a proof to me, but was simply unsure that you were providing a proof. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What ever you take to be your coefficient ring, will consist of constant  polynomials not divisible by $(x-1)$, and will therefore be an example of a set of polynomials that aren't in $\langle x-1 \rangle  $.

Answer (score 0):

The set of all polynomials divisible by $(x−1)$ is a (maximal) ideal of $P$ considered as a ring. Thus cannot be $P$ itself.